# How do you print a linked list recursively in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I followed a guide on youtube by Paul Programming to create this linked list. Now I want to expand on it. I am trying to learn how to do recursive functions.

The error I am getting is that `head` isn't declared in main.cpp. I was wondering if anyone could shed some light on the issue I am having.

Code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "linkedlist.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    List list;
    list.addNode(1);
    list.addNode(2);
    list.addNode(3);
    list.addNode(4);
    list.addNode(5);

    cout << "Printing list" << endl;
    list.printList();

    cout << "Printing list recursively" << endl;
    list.printListRecur(head);

    return 0;

}
```

linkedlist.h:

```
#ifndef _LINKEDLISTHEADER_
#define _LINKEDLISTHEADER_

class List{
private:

    typedef struct node{
            int data;
            node* next;
    }* nodePtr;

    nodePtr head;
    nodePtr curr;
    nodePtr temp;

public:

    List();

    void addNode(int addData);
    void deleteNode(int delData);
    void printList();

    void printListRecur(nodePtr head);
    };

#endif
```

linkedlist.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "linkedlist.h"

using namespace std;

List::List()
{
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

void List::addNode(int addData)
{
    nodePtr n = new node;
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = addData;

    if(head != NULL)
    {
            curr = head;

            while(curr->next != NULL)
            {
                    curr = curr->next;
            }

            curr->next = n;
    }
    else
    {
            head = n;
    }
}

void List::deleteNode(int delData)
{
    nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    curr = head;

    while(curr != NULL && curr->data != delData)
    {
            temp = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
    }

    if(curr == NULL)
    {
            cout << delData << " was not in the list." << endl;
            delete delPtr;
    }
    else
    {
            delPtr = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            temp->next = curr;
            if(delPtr == head)
            {
                    head = head->next;
                    temp = NULL;
            }
            delete delPtr;

            cout << "The value " << delData << " was deleted" << endl;

    }
}

void List::printList()
{
    curr = head;

    while(curr != NULL)
    {
            cout << curr->data << endl;
            curr = curr->next;
    }
}

void List::printListRecur(nodePtr head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
    {
            return;
    }

    cout << head->data <<endl;

    printListRecur(head->next);
}
```

Comment: You mean to do `list.printListRecur(list.head)` but then `head` is a private member so you should have an overload of `printListRecur` in your class that takes no arguments and simply forwards to `printListRecur(this->head)`.

Comment: `_LINKEDLISTHEADER_` name is reserved for the implementation. By defining it, your program has undefined behaviour. Pick a different name that isn't reserved.

Comment: You can make a helper function that will pass private head to printListRecur and call it instead.

Comment: In general you DON'T recursively print a linked list. Get this working to get a good grade on the assignment, but in real-life code stick to iteration.

Comment: On a side note, `curr` and `temp` do not belong as members of the `List` class, they should be local variables inside of the methods that use them. And `addNode()` can be greatly simplified. And `deleteNode()` should not call `delete delPtr;` when `curr` is `NULL`.

Comment: Yeah, with recursion, you always need to consider iteration depth. Recursing through linked list uses stack space *k N*, where *N* is list length (unless using language which *quarantees* tail recursion). To use recursion, you generally want algorithm to use stack space *k log N* or something like that (examples, merge sort or quick sort). So, keep that in mind for "real" applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use recursion, you need to have the passed and returned data to be the same type, i.e, the function should consume a `Node` and then return a `Node`, recursion call will not be formed if function consumes a `List` but return a `Node`.

From my understanding, `List` can be a wrapper class for `Node`. To give you a very simple example:

```
class List {
    struct Node {
        int data; 
        Node *next;

        void print();
        ...
    };

    Node *head;

public:
    void print();
    ...
};

void List::Node::print() {
    std::cout << data << endl;
    if (next) next->print();
}

void List::print() {
    if (head) head->print();
}
```

`List` will have all the interface methods that a client might need, but the actual work is done by the methods of `Node`, **if you want to go with the recursion way** (iteration is more frequently used since recursion consumes much more memory space).

Comment: "*To use recursion, you need to have the passed and returned data to be the same type*" - recursion does not require a return type. It technically doesn't require an input parameter, either. In its simplest form, recursion is just a function calling itself, nothing more. I like your use of a method on the `node` struct, though. It makes the implementation cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my buggy code and you are absolutely correct. Recursive function calls do not require functions to have parameters and return values. The "passed/returned" in my answer do not refer to "parameter/return value",  I should have used better wording.

Answer (score 0):

`head` is a (private) member of the `List` class.  There is no variable named `head` in `main()`, that is why the compiler is complaining.

I would suggest either:

- adding a method to `List` to return the `head` node, then you can pass it to `printListRecur()`:

  ```
  class List {
      ...
  public:
      ...
      nodePtr getHead() { return head; }
      ...
      void printListRecur(nodePtr node);
      ...
  };

  list.printListRecur(list.getHead());
  ```
- remove the input parameter from `printListRecur()`, and then define a private method for `printListRecur()` to call recursively, passing it the `head` node:

  ```
  class List {
  private:
      ...
      void internalPrintListRecur(nodePtr node);
      ...
  public:
      ...
      void printListRecur();
      ...
  };

  void List::internalPrintListRecur(nodePtr node)
  {
      if (node)
      {
          cout << node->data <<endl;
          internalPrintListRecur(node->next);
      }
  }

  void List::printListRecur()
  {
      internalPrintListRecur(head);
  }
  ```

But, as others stated in comments, iterating through the list recursively is not usually desired due to the fact that data may have to be pushed onto the call stack on each iteration. Using recursion to iterate a large list is subject to a stack overflow error, unless the code is written in a way that allows the compiler to apply tail call optimization to avoid the stack error.

In this example, it is better to just use a simple iterative loop instead, like your `printList()` is already using.  Don't use recursion.